# Feast of achashverosh connected to failed 70 year prophecy

Tags: midrash, megillat-esther, time, parties-celebrations

What is the source where it actually mentions that one of the reasons for the feast of Achashverosh was celebrating the "failed" prophecy of Yirmiyahu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the [*Bavli*, *M'gila*  11 *amud* 2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.11b.12).

Comment: Thank you. Although, this gemara does not explicitly connect the feast with the failed calculation.

Comment: @TheTargum that is the context, starting here, https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.11b.6  where the Talmud asks why the previous verse says it was when the king sat on the throne, but then says it was the 3rd year. In other words, why only make the party on the 3rd year.

Comment: @Menachem Thank You